# How do you make a matrix out of vectors in eigen?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, eigen

I have four column vectors. I need to append them to make a four by four matrix. Is there a constructor or something for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialise Eigen::vector with std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036818/initialise-eigenvector-with-stdvector)

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Eigen has its own matrices and vectors. He is asking about them I guess, not using `std::vector`.

Comment: @HakanDemir it was some time ago, but i guess what i was going for was that you could use a vector to initialise it. Anyway, not a dupe.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can also append them using the comma initializer syntax:

```
m << v1, v2, v3, v4;
```

The matrix `m` must have been properly resized first.

Comment: Does this copy the vectors `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and `v4`? Is it possibly to create the matrix `m` using the data in the vectors without copying them? maybe a const reference or something like that?

Comment: What if `v{i}` is row vectors?

Comment: Then they be stacked up row by row, as you would expect.

Comment: Does not seem to work with current eigen.

Answer (score 12):

A quick check on the [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aa8716d44f51321072ee5c88665c28813):

```
Vector4f v1(1,0,0,0);
Vector4f v2(0,1,0,0);
Vector4f v3(0,0,1,0);
Vector4f v4(0,0,0,1);
Matrix4f m;

m.row(0) = v1;
m.row(1) = v2;
m.row(2) = v3;
m.row(3) = v4;

std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

output:

```
1,0,0,0
0,1,0,0
0,0,1,0
0,0,0,1
```