# typecasting Eigen::VectorXd to std::vector

Tags: c++, eigen

Their are many links to go the other way round but I am unable to find to get a std::vector from a Eigen::Matrix or Eigen::VectorXd in my specific case.

Comment: Since I had a hard time finding the "many links to go the other way round", consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613025/10220019 for the other way around. I hope this saves some people some time

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
vector<int> vec(mat.data(), mat.data() + mat.rows() * mat.cols());
```

Comment: `mat.rows() * mat.cols()` can be simplified to `mat.size()`, however, be aware that this solution only work for a plain `Matrix<>` object, while using a `Map<>` as in my answer works for sub-matrices too.

Comment: If someone needs to copy a row of a matrix into a vector:

`vector<double> vec(arr.cols());
Map<RowVectorXd>(&vec[0], 1, mat.cols()) = mat.row(0);`

Answer (score 62):

You cannot typecast, but you can easily copy the data:

```
VectorXd v1;
v1 = ...;
vector<double> v2;
v2.resize(v1.size());
VectorXd::Map(&v2[0], v1.size()) = v1;
```

Comment: heyy thankyou for reply.. but i found the above answer more clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from and to Eigen vector :

```
    //init a first vector
    std::vector<float> v1;
    v1.push_back(0.5);
    v1.push_back(1.5);
    v1.push_back(2.5);
    v1.push_back(3.5);

    //from v1 to an eignen vector
    float* ptr_data = &v1[0];
    Eigen::VectorXf v2 = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf, Eigen::Unaligned>(v1.data(), v1.size());

    //from the eigen vector to the std vector
    std::vector<float> v3(&v2[0], v2.data()+v2.cols()*v2.rows());


    //to check
    for(int i = 0; i < v1.size() ; i++){
        std::cout << std::to_string(v1[i]) << " | " << std::to_string(v2[i]) << " | " << std::to_string(v3[i]) << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: `v1.data()` should be replaced by `ptr_data`, no?