# Copy a raw buffer in to an Eigen::ArrayXf

Tags: eigen

I have a pointer to some floating point data that I'd like to copy in to an Eigen::ArrayXf. Is there a simple way of doing this other than looping through the memory and assigning values to the Eigen::ArrayXf?

Something along the lines of:

```
float* someData = new float[64];
...
Eigen::ArrayXf newArary( 64 );
newArray.data() = someData;
```

Comment: See this doc [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) on `Eigen::Map`, and this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036818/initialise-eigenvector-with-stdvector/17037695#17037695).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
Eigen::ArrayXf newArary(Eigen::ArrayXf::Map(someData, 64));
```

You can also just use the mapped data directly.
Check the map tutorial for more details and alternative syntax:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to copy from and std::vector, then see the assignment operator in the [Eigen Do Better](http://eigendobetter.com) library.