# Constructing Eigen::Array from Eigen::Map, how does it work?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

In my project I have written the following code:

```
Eigen::ArrayXf foo(const Eigen::ArrayXcf &src)
{
    auto * output = new float[src.size()];
    //Fill the data here
    return Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXf>(output, src.size());
}
```

Note that the stuff constructed in return statement is an `Eigen::Map`, but compiler does not complain anything so there must be a conversion. Therefore I have the following questions:

1. How does this conversion happen? By making a deep copy of original data or just changing ownership?
2. Is this code OK? Does it cause undefined behaviours or memory leaks?
3. If I want the returned `Eigen::Array` owns the data in `*output` instead of copying it, and release this block of memory on destruction, how can I achieve this? At [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037695/9555853) I noticed `Eigen::Array` and `Eigen::Matrix` can be initialized with raw data pointer, but it seems only work on fixed size arrays and matrices. This function is going to be called frequently so I do care about the efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayXf` has an implicit constructor from `Map<ArrayXf>` (in fact from any `ArrayBase<...>` object) which makes a deep copy of the content.
From Eigen's point of view your code is safe, however you leak memory, since you never de-allocate the `float* output` data. Generally, `new` should be avoided or at least encapsulated when writing clean C++ code.

You can make your code much easier, by directly allocating the `Array` object you want to return later (there won't be a copy on any non-ancient C++ compiler, due to RVO (return value optimization)):

```
Eigen::ArrayXf foo(const Eigen::ArrayXcf &src)
{
    Eigen::ArrayXf output_array(src.size());
    float * output = output_array.data();
    //Fill the data here
    return output_array;
}
```

If you want to avoid memory allocation (inside the function) entirely, you need to elaborate at what place the memory shall actually be allocated. You could just construct an `Array` object at that place and pass it by reference to your function (or make it a member variable of a class which has `foo` as a member function).

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful. C++ is indeed complicated, even if you understand language core mechanism well, the best practice is still not easy to figure out sometimes. Allocate first and then peek into it then return by value is a great idea here.