# std::vector to Eigen::VectorXf

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

I have a vector

```
int N = 100;
std::vector<float> v(N, 1.0f);
```

which I'd like to convert to an Eigen vector type ( `Eigen::VectorXf`?) I have tried

```
Eigen::VectorXf ev(N);  
ev = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf>(&v[0], N);
```

but I am not sure if it right or wrong. I can only see `ev` has 1 value in my visual studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialise Eigen::vector with std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036818/initialise-eigenvector-with-stdvector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct. No need to initialize `ev(N)`, though. You can just write

```
Eigen::VectorXf ev = Eigen::VectorXf::Map(&v[0], N);
```